# How get variable address?

Tags: variables, memory, erlang

i have some strange question.
For example we have

```
ets:tab2list(test).
[{a,1}, {b,2}].
```

Or `gen_server` which has in state `same list.`
Is there any way how we can get memory address for example for {a, 1} or '1'?
will thanks for any opinions

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MartinTörnwall already needn't. it was just awful issue description.
now only interest if it's possible.
seems like it isn't according to https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Erlang/Omit